# Adding an object from file into program

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I'm programming a game and in the program I need to add new enemies based off of a file. Right now my problem is that I've run into an infinite while loop when trying to read this file. I'm relatively new to programming so I'm not exactly sure how to fix this. Here is the problem code. An example of how the entry in the file looks is: "Troll,6,4,1". Thank you for your help.

```
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        while(input.hasNext());
        {
            input.useDelimiter(",|\n");
            String name = input.next();
            int strength = input.nextInt();
            int speed = input.nextInt();
            int numVials = input.nextInt();
            Enemy newEnemy = new Enemy(name, strength, speed, numVials);
            opponents.add(newEnemy);
            input.close();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop is being caused because of the `;` after your `while` statement. Also I believe there is a logic related issue with your code. We can read each line of the file, then split the each line based on the ',' by using the following code :

```
        String line[]; 
        do {
            line = input.next().split(",");
            String name = line[0];
            int strength = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
            int speed = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
            int numVials = Integer.parseInt(line[3]);
            Enemy newEnemy = new Enemy(name, strength, speed, numVials);
            opponents.add(newEnemy);
            input.close();
        } while (input.hasNext());
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, I had accidentally renamed the Scanner variable to `read`

Comment: Okay that part works now but I'm getting array out of bounds exception on the line[1] part.

Comment: Hmm, what is your input? I've tried by placing `Troll,6,4,1` in the first line of the file, it worked fine.

Comment: It's the same. Troll,6,4,1

Comment: I figured it out. It works. I had an opponent called wall with no values

Comment: That's great. As a side note, before the `Integer.parseInt(...)` we can add a check to see if we have a value in the index before actually parsing it.

Comment: if(line[1] != null && line[1].trim().matches("^[0-9]*$")) Here we check if the string is not null and whether the String contains only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`input.hasNext()` does not move the pointer to the next line.

After you call `hasNext()` the first time, if you don't read from the file, `hasNext()` will always return true. Because the front of the input doesn't change.

Try this:

```
try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        String x = null;

        while((x = input.next()) != null)
        {
        input.useDelimiter(",|\n");
        String name = input.next();
        int strength = input.nextInt();
        int speed = input.nextInt();
        int numVials = input.nextInt();
        Enemy newEnemy = new Enemy(name, strength, speed, numVials);
        opponents.add(newEnemy);
        input.close();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I tried running your code, doesn't seem to work. Could you check it once?

Answer (score 1):

You have written : while(input.hasNext());

You need to remove the semi colon first.

Next you have closed the input within the loop that also needs to be done outside the loop as after the first time the input being closed will not get processed and will give exception.